# Error when I subtract from the ASCII value

Tags: c

I copied a piece of code i found online that encrypts a string and i added the function of choosing the encryption key. However, i get an error

```
int main()
{
   int i, x, v;
   char str[100];

   printf("\nPlease enter a string:\t");
   gets(str);
   printf("\nPlease enter encryption key:\t"); //i leave a message next to the lines of code i added myself like here
   scanf("%d", &v);//here

   printf("\nPlease choose following options:\n");
   printf("1 = Encrypt the string.\n");
   printf("2 = Decrypt the string.\n");
   scanf("%d", &x);

   switch(x)
   {
   case 1:
      for(i = 0; (i < 100 && str[i] != '\0'); i++)
        str[i] = str[i] + &v;// here i changed the value from 3 to the value of int v

      printf("\nEncrypted string: %s\n", str);
      break;

   case 2:
      for(i = 0; (i < 100 && str[i] != '\0'); i++)
        str[i] = str[i] - &v;/*here i changed the value from 3 to the value of int v as well,
the error message appears here, which is strange since when i add the value it works fine but when i subtract it 
i get this error message 
" error: invalid operands to binary - (have 'int' and 'int *') " */

      printf("\nDecrypted string: %s\n", str);
      break;

   default:
      printf("\nError\n");
   }
   return 0;
}
```

However, if I use the same code but instead of &v I use any number it works fine

```
int main()
{
   int i, x, v;
   char str[100];

   printf("\nPlease enter a string:\t");
   gets(str);
   printf("\nPlease enter encryption key:\t");
   scanf("%d", &v);

   printf("\nPlease choose following options:\n");
   printf("1 = Encrypt the string.\n");
   printf("2 = Decrypt the string.\n");
   scanf("%d", &x);

   switch(x)
   {
   case 1:
      for(i = 0; (i < 100 && str[i] != '\0'); i++)
        str[i] = str[i] + &v;

      printf("\nEncrypted string: %s\n", str);
      break;

   case 2:
      for(i = 0; (i < 100 && str[i] != '\0'); i++)
        str[i] = str[i] - 3;//here

      printf("\nDecrypted string: %s\n", str);
      break;

   default:
      printf("\nError\n");
   }
   return 0;
}
```

I can't figure out why this is happening especially on subtraction and not on addition

Comment: 'str[i] = str[i] - &v;' - you should look up what the '&' operator does and, so, understand why and where it is required.

Comment: You're adding address of variable v in &v, just take v.

Comment: @MartinJames or just tell him what it does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`&` is an operator in C, and it returns the address of its argument. So, in your case `&v` returns address of v, and not value stored in v. So basically, both `str[i] = str[i] + &v` and `str[i] = str[i] - &v` are wrong. You need to change them to `str[i] = str[i] + v` and `str[i] = str[i] - v`. Also, you may want to understand pointers in C properly before going anymore deep in C.

To know why first case is not showing an error, you must know about pointer operations in C. Basically, you can add or subtract an integer x to a address a (supposedly to get the data at a+x and a-x). So `int* + int` and `int* - int` are valid.

Since `str[i] + &v` is of type `int + int*`, and addition is commutative, you are not getting an error. But note that, result of this is `int*` and not `int`. So, a good enough compiler/IDE will warn here for implicit cast from `int*` to `int` when you assign the result of addition in `str[i] = str[i] + &v`.

However, `str[i] - &v` is of type `int - int*`, and subtraction is not commutative. So, it is indeed invalid in C and you get an error.

Comment: Thanks a ton! I will sure check pointers a bit more, I thought using & meant that it subtracts the value of the integer. Again, thanks for taking the time to answer!

Comment: Glad to help, if this answer solved your problem please mark it as accepted by clicking the check mark next to the answer. see: [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234) for more information. Welcome to StackOverflow !!